# ParsleyJS - reset field on "backspace" (when deleting input)

Tags: parsley.js

I was wondering how to `reset()` a ParsleyJS field if a user is deleting his input.

When I enter some input in the "First Name" field it validates successfully on `input`. Good.

If I now figure out that I made a typo while filling out that field, and I hit the backspace button on my keyboard until it is empty, it invalidates with `parsley-error`. However, the other empty fields which I didn't fill out yet, e.g. "Last Name", are neither valid nor invalid.

So the form now shows a red/parsley-error but empty "First Name" field and a white and empty "Last Name" field, whereas both fields should look the same: white (not yet validated) and empty.

Thereofor, I think it would be logical that a field would, once emptied, be handled like a field that has never been filled. So neither `parsley-success` nor `parsley-error` should fire, or respectively, it should `reset()`. How can I achieve this?

I appreciate any input from your end!

Thanks

Comment: What you are describing is not the out-of-the-box behavior. Enter a first name, tab out, get back in, delete it, tab out, you won't get an error.

Comment: Hi @Marc-AndréLafortune when I do as you explained, enter first name, tab out (to the next field last name), click back into first name and delete it, tab out - it does keep the `parsley-error` class and invalidates it. I forked your "Simple Form example" [link](http://codepen.io/bauhausweb/pen/LbXzQY) and you can see a similar behaviour: if you validate the empty form, the e-mail field fails and gives the error message. If you now start typing an e-mail, the form successfully validates. But if you delete this e-mail address now, the field turns red again.

Comment: Or if you enter an incomplete e-mail address, and click into Full Name, the e-mail address validation fails. If you now click back into the e-mail field and delete the incomplete e-mail address, the field remains invalid/red.

Comment: "If you validate the empty form" contradicts "However, the other empty fields which I didn't fill out yet, e.g. "Last Name", are neither valid nor invalid" of your original question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a simple way to achieve what you want and can only discourage you from going against Parsley.

It is Parsley's contention that once you've tried to validate an invalid entry (for `required` fields that means clicking on 'Submit'), that you should be mostly done entering all the info. At that point, you probably want to click on 'Submit' again, and Parsley will show you all the errors that prevent you from doing that, no need to click 'Submit' over and over again.

I fail to see why a user would want to empty out a field at that point, and if she did why she'd want to keep it empty for more than half a second, or why she'd be confused by the fact that there's an error doing so.

Good luck